# Can only boot notebook with disabled driver signature enforcement after crash

Tags: windows-10, boot, drivers

I am running Windows 10 Enterprise Edition on an Acer notebook.
Yesterday there was a short power outage, for about 5 seconds, which crashed my computer. After that I couldn't boot normally into Windows anymore. The computer just stays stuck at the Acer logo, even when trying to boot in safe mode.

So, I tried various things from the Windows Automatic Repair menu and the console I could access through that.
But nothing I did there helped.

After all that I tried out all the options in the Startup Settings and with #7 Disable driver signature enforcement I can actually get into Windows again.
When I boot like that, it seems to boot rather slowly though.

I ran sigverif and that shows 2 files that haven't been signed.

- basicrenderer.sys version: 10.0.16299.19
- bthport.sys version: 10.0.16299.64

- How can I fix that and sign these drivers? I don't want to run the computer with that permanently disabled.
- And are these 2 files not being signed even the actual reason for me not being able to boot Windows?
- Is it possible that that happened when my computer suddenly crashed?

I also ran sfc /scannow and that returned:

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.

I was then looking into CBS.log to find that, but that file has 37492 lines and I don't know what to search for.

- Is that also related to the startup issue?
- How can I find which corrupted files it hasn't been able to fix?

I also had a look into SRTlog and it says there: 
- Number of root causes = 1
- all the error codes are 0x0
- Startup Repair has tried several times but still cannot determine the cause of the problem.

- What is that telling me about the problem?